# definition of a functor in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, functor

I have to define the signature `tEXP` of a functor which, starting from a module `A` with signature `tARITH`, constructs an abstract type representing expressions. This type of expressions will be named `t`.
the signature have to declare different operations to build an expression:

- from a constant of type A.t (cst operation)
- as the opposite of an expression (opp)
- as an operation on two expressions (add and mul)
- Finally, a compute operation will describe the evaluation of an expression to obtain its value (of type A.t).

I have written this so far :

```
module type tARITH = sig 
  type t
  val zero : t
  val one : t
  val add : t -> t -> t
  val mul : t -> t -> t
  val opp : t -> t
  val of_int : int -> t 
  val to_string : t -> string
end 

module INT : tARITH = struct
  type t = int
  let zero = 0;;
  let one =1;;
  let add x y = x+y;;
  let mul x y = x*y;;
  let opp x = -x;;
  let of_int x= x;;
  let to_string x= string_of_int x;; 
end ;; 

type m3 = Zero | Un | Deux
          
module M3:tARITH = struct
  type t = m3
  let zero = Zero;;
  let one = Un;;
  let add m n = if m=Zero && n=Zero || n=Un && m=Deux || m=Un && n=Deux then Zero
    else if m=Deux && n=Zero || m=Un && n=Un || m=Zero && n=Deux then Deux 
    else Un;;
  let mul m n = if m=Deux && n=Deux || m=Un && n=Un then Un
    else if m=Deux && n=Un || n=Deux && m=Un then Deux
    else Zero;;
  let opp m = match m with 
    |Zero->Zero
    |Un->Deux
    |Deux->Un;;
  let of_int m = match (m mod 3) with 
    |0->Zero
    |1->Un
    |2->Deux 
    |(-1)->opp Un
    |(-2)->opp Deux 
    |_->Zero;;
  let to_string x = match x with
    |Zero->"0"
    |Un->"1"
    |Deux->"2" ;;
end;;
```

and here the signature of tEXP :

```
module type tEXP =
sig
  type t = Constante of m3 | Somme of t*t | Produit of t*t 
  val cst t -> t;;
  val opp x -> t ;;
  val add x -> y -> t 
  val mul x -> y -> t
  val compute x -> A.x;;
end ;;

module EXP = functor (A: tARITH)-> struct
   type t = Constante of m3 | Somme of t*t | Produit of t*t 
   let cst x = x;;
   let opp x = match x with 
     |Constante(x) -> x 
     |Constante(x)-> x
     |Somme(x,y)-> A.plus (calculer x) (calculer y)
     |Produit(x,y)-> A.mult (calculer x) (calculer y) ;;
   let  add x y = A.plus (calculer x) (calculer y);;
   let mul x y = A.mul (calculer x) (calculer y) ;;
   let compute x = A.x;;
 end;;
```

I get an error at "sig" and the first "x", I don't really know why.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I have the impression that you simply have no function named `A.plus`. Maybe you meant `A.add`?

Comment: Trying to run this code I get an "Unbound type constructor m3". Please make sure your question includes a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I have just edited it

Comment: @Alice there are still some unbound values, probably because you forgot to translate them (you call `calculer` but only define `compute`). Besides that, you pattern-match twice the same pattern `Constante x`...

Comment: Defining a type for a function is done with `val <function> : <type>`, not `val <function> <type>`. It looks like an overly complicated question for a simple syntax error. Looks like `tARITH` was given to you and you tried to do the same without noticing you forgot the `:`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. Here is the final answer:

```
module type tEXP = functor (A : tARITH) -> sig
  type t
  val cst : A.t -> t
  val opp : t -> t
  val add : t -> t -> t
  val mul : t -> t -> t
  val compute : t -> A.t 
end;;

module EXP = functor (A : tARITH) -> struct
  type t = Const of A.t | Opp of t | Add of t*t | Mul of t*t
  let cst c = Const (c)
  let add ex1 ex2 = Add (ex1, ex2)
  let opp exp = Opp (exp) 
  let mul ex1 ex2 = Mul (ex1, ex2)
  let rec compute expr = match expr with 
      Const (c) -> c
    | Opp (e) -> A.opp (compute e)
    | Add(e1, e2) -> A.add (compute e1) (compute e2)
    | Mul(e1, e2) -> A.mul (compute e1) (compute e2)
end;;
```